# mercurial abort: Input/output error,transaction abort! rollback completed

Tags: mercurial, transactions, rollback, abort

i am trying to pull from a repository in bitbucket.

i am giving

```
bash-4.1$ hg pull https://sat801@bitbucket.org/golmschenk/i4330-notification
```

but it shows like this

```
pulling from https://sat801@bitbucket.org/golmschenk/i4330-notification
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: Input/output error
bash-4.1$
```

please let me know how to solve this problem. thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (even with the `sat801@` in the URL) so all I can do is guess. The most likely reason is a problem writing to the repository on your local disk. Check if any of the following are true:

1. You are trying to write to a read-only filesystem;
2. You don't have permission to write where the repository resides;
3. Your disk is full;
4. You have filesystem corruption;
5. You have a failing drive.